# Cropped image when sharing on facebook

Tags: php, facebook, symfony1

i have an share button on my page and have too the op:image, op:width: and op:height on my meta tags. 
When user's share the page, sometimes images get an crop of top left and not take the full image. In the box when user's preview what will share the image is fine, but when in the wall the image is get the crop.

I google it but not had any solid answer. Someone can help me ?

This is my code in symfony framework:

```
    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $response->addMeta("og:image", "http://www.mydomain/upload/noticias/". $this->tbnews[0]->getImagem());
    $response->addMeta("og:title", $this->tbnews[0]->getTitulo());
    $response->addMeta("og:description", $this->tbnews[0]->getApoio());
    $response->addMeta("og:image:width", "400px");
    $response->addMeta("og:image:height", "209px");
```

---

```
   <div class="col-md-1">
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://www.mydomain/noticias/index/<?php echo $noticia[0]->getId()?>&title=<?php echo $noticia[0]->getTitulo()?>"> 
            <img class="fb-share-button" src="/images/fb.png" with='48px' height='48px' alt="Compartilhe essa notÃ­cia no seu Facebook."> 
        </a>
    </div>
```

[image]

the first image is on box before share, when you confirm that.

[image]

the second image is the shared on facebook feed news, is how appear to users.

Comment: we would not be able to help you much without looking at your code.

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to share?

Comment: you can see the url in first block code, is og:image content.